# Rails - custom validation called on association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am experiencing problems with a custom validation in rails.

I have a very simple has_many_through association:

```
class Event
  has_many :event_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :event_tags
end

class Tag
  has_many :event_tags
  has_many :events, through: :event_tags
end

class EventTag
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

I have a validation on my Tag model, which is just a uniqueness, but slightly too complicated to be done using just a scope. I therefore have in my model:

```
validate :name_is_unique_in_scope
...
def name_is_unique_in_scope
  errors.add(:base, 'not unique') if not_unique #this is simplified
end
```

This works perfectly well when I create a new tag.

Now, when I create a new Event, I have a field for the association in my Simple Form:

```
<%= f.association :tags, collection: @tags, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, label: false, required: true, include_hidden: false, input_html: { class: 'form-control', id: 'form-event-tags', multiple: 'multiple' }%>
```

and in  the create action of my controller:

```
@event.tag_ids = params[:event][:tag_ids]
```

which also used to work perfectly fine.

Now the problem is, since I have my custom validation in place, the custom validation of the Tag model is being called and my association can't be created. There is no validation in my EventTag model, so I really don't understand why this is being called whereas I am not creating a new Tag object.

If I change this validation to a standard

```
validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
```

this is working again.

Thanks

Comment: what are the validations on your `Event` object?

Comment: I don't have any for the moment

Comment: so this occurs on update action, not create?

Comment: no it is on the create action, sorry for the mistake, corrected it.

Comment: What does the create action in your Event controller look like?